# How can I make an HTML input element in a WAI-ARIA tree accessible to VoiceOver in Safari?

Tags: html, safari, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

I want to put an `<input>` element inside an element with `role="tree"` like this:

```html
<div role="tree">
  <div role="treeitem">
    <h1>Tree Input</h1>
    <input>
    <a href="#">Submit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I do this, I am unable to access the `<input>` element using my screen reader – VoiceOver in Safari on OS X. When I navigate the page (using the VO+arrow commands), the text box is skipped.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update:** I tested the code in Chrome with the ChromeVox screen reader, and I didn't have the problem. I agree with unobf's comment that this looks like a bug with VoiceOver/Safari. I emailed accessibility@apple.com about it, but I haven't got a reply. I'll change the title of this question to be specific to VoiceOver/Safari and post about it in Apple's support forum.

Comment: looks like a bug send it to accessibility@apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple Accessibility, this is a bug. I guess I did nothing wrong and that I'll just have to wait for a fix.

The bug is in WebKit, an open-source layout engine used by Safari. A bug report can be found [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=142196).